# насколько я понимаю swift не поддерживает множественное наследование, тогда почему этот кусок кода работает?

Tags: swift, наследование

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что ObservableObject и CLLocationManagerDelegate это протоколы, а не классы. Наследование относится к классам.